# File transfer from Application server to Db Server without a shared folder access but using Service Account

Tags: databases

I am working as a Business Analyst for an IT firm. My team has stumbled upon a certain feature where they are required to use Service account. 
We are working for a Bank and they have strong policies of keeping no Shared folder on Db server, for this they have advised us and provided us Service accounts with help of their server team.
Naturally my team is unaware on how to use this Service account for transferring the file From App server A to Db server B and thus i will be needing help from you guys.

If you ask me i dont know exactly what a service account is, but judging by the name it is a credentials which allows access within different servers.
Can anyone advice on how to use this for file tranfer?

Comment: Hello Ravish, welcome. Can you give us some idea of what software and operating environment you're dealing with?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general lack of understanding here.  I suspect your company doesn't understand your "requirement" and the Server team has provided something that either *won't* do the job or your team don't know *how* to make it work.

You say that you "need" to get a file onto a Database server - my first question would be - "**why**"?

What's *in* this file that you need to put it *anywhere near* the Database server?

Your company has a Policy against doing this through file shares on the Database server.  [Being a DBA] I completely understand (and *agree*) with this Policy.

On its own, a Service Account isn't going to be much use to you.
You *might* be able to use it with some File Transfer utility to copy the file but, again, *why* do you want to do this?

Take a step back and describe the "Big Picture" problem that you're trying to solve here.